# Regex expression for three strings with a delimiter

Tags: regex, shopify

I am setting up a simple solution to add multiple images to shopify using meta data. And I want to follow the following data structure `String|String|String` (`VariantParentName|VariantName|URL or Color|Red|https://cdn.shopify.com/blahblah/file.jpg`).

I am trying to use regex101 builder in an online tool but I am struggling with it. Any help would be appreciate to solve this pattern.

Comment: The character `|` denotes alternates.  `a|b` = "a or b".  In order to put a literal `|` you need to escape it.  Maybe you should try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tackle the pattern you provided you could try a regex like -

```
\w+\|\w+\|https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

What this does is the `\w+` matches any word characters while the `\|` actually looks for the `|` char (since it is escaped) and the last chunk is more specifically looking for a web URL that has http(s) (as seen in your example). You cant just use `\w+` for the url since your url has non word chars like `:` and `\`

Comment: the regex for URL matching was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)